How can I make Atril remember its previous window size & previous document-location?
I have been using atril to view pdf documents for sometime.  It is great, except (at least in my environment) it has 2 irritating issues:

It always opens documents in a tiny window - I have to use the mouse to resize the window
It always starts the document on the first page (unless I specify a page number through command-line options)

Is there a way I can make it remember its previous window-size & document-page-number?
I use openbox (if that helps).
